# How to remotely turn "up" sounds?

Tags: audio

So I have to Skype with someone, but he is not...well let's just say not a "geek", so I have to log in via SSH to his Fedora machine, and turn on sound [because he can't hear me when using Skype, but I can hear him, so the sound is turned off/too quiet on his side]. How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can usually use `alsamixer` from a command line over SSH to control ALSA sound levels. For a less graphical alternative you can use `amixer`.

If the system uses OSS instead of ALSA, `aumix` should do the job.

As a last resort you could use X forwarding to send any other graphical sound control program back to your desktop for control.

Comment: ALSA also has `amixer`, that one is CLI only, without the ncurses TUI.

Comment: A similar alternative for OSS is [aumix](http://jpj.net/~trevor/aumix.html).

Comment: ssh -C -X user@IPADDRESS gnome-volume-control  ??

Comment: @LanceBaynes Using a graphical mixer over ssh is an overkill and it can only work if the host `sshd` server has `X11Forwarding` enabled (which does not seem a good idea in the described scenario).